# Cannot build source code in Xcode 4.1 with iOS 4.3.5 device

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, ios4, xcode4.1

I have been developing in Xcode 4.1 with iphone of iOS 4.3.5. It was fine without a version mismatch problem. Today, I connected another iphone which has the same version of iOS (4.3.5) and I could not build source code on to the device. The organizer window said,

> The version of iOS on “Hee’s iPhone” does not match any of the
>   versions of iOS  supported for development with this installation of
>   the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed
>   below, or update to the latest version of the iOS SDK; which is
>   available here.

I know it will be solved if I update Xcode or downgrade iPhone. However, I want to know other options if there are any. I really wonder why some devices are fine but others are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put additional SDKs/Symbols for the iPhoneOS/iPhoneSimulator platforms inside:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/[insert ios version folder here]
```

and

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/[insert ios version folder here]
```

What I do is download old xcode and new beta xcode, install them to something like /Developer-3.2.3/, then symlink/alias the folders above from the /Developer-3.2.3 to the /Developer.

This lets my 4.1 xcode test on an iOS5.0 phone!  The directory paths above might not be exact as I am writing this from my phone but they areaomething close to that.  When I get back to my computer I will make sure those directories are correct.

For the simulator versions it would be:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/SDK/...
```

---

## Edit (back at my computer):

Here is what my Developer directories looks like:

```
[ 17:49 root@MacBookPro / ]# ll
drwxrwxr-x+ 44 root      admin      1.5K Sep 20 12:37 Applications
drwxrwxr-x  15 root      admin      510B Sep 20 13:27 Developer
drwxrwxr-x@ 17 root      admin      578B Sep 20 13:12 Developer-3.2.4
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 root      admin      340B Sep 20 13:54 Developer-3.2.5
drwxrwxr-x@ 18 root      admin      612B Sep 20 13:44 Developer-4.2-beta7

[ 17:46 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs ]# ll
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75B Sep 20 13:53 iPhoneOS3.2.sdk -> /Developer-3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  wheel   272B Sep 20 13:26 iPhoneOS4.3.sdk
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    79B Sep 21 12:50 iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -> /Developer-4.2-beta7/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk

[ 17:46 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer ]# cd ../../DeviceSupport/
[ 17:46 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# ll
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.0
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.1
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.1.2
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.1.3
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.2
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.2.1
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 3.2.2
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.0
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.0.1
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.0.2
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.1
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.2
drwxrwxr-x  5 root      admin   170B Sep 20 13:26 4.3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin    77B Sep 21 12:54 5.0 (9A5313e) -> /Developer-4.2-beta7/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5313e)/
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root      admin    13B Sep 21 12:54 Latest -> 5.0 (9A5313e)
[ 17:46 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]#
```

In order to do this, you need to install the different versions of Xcode that have different iOS SDKs.  To achieve the above, I only installed Xcode 3.2.4, 3.2.4, 4.1, and 4.2 (beta).  I use 4.1 as my main `/Developer` directory.

Once each Xcode is installed into seperate locations, this is how you would symlink the Symbols/SDKs directories from a non-primary Xcode install to your main install path:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
[ 17:54 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
[ 17:54 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# ln -sf "/Developer-4.2-beta7/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/5.0 (9A5313e)/" "5.0 (9A5313e)"
[ 17:54 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# cd ../Developer/SDKs
[ 17:54 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# ln -sf "/Developer-3.2.4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.2.sdk" "iPhoneOS3.2.sdk"
[ 17:54 root@MacBookPro /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport ]# ln -sf "/Developer-4.2-beta7/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk" "iPhoneOS5.0.sdk"
```

After symlinking each SDK/Symbol directory in your main `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` and `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs` directories, open up Xcode, and you should be able to see your device and use it to test builds, etc.

---

Edit 2 (commands explained):

`ll` is an `alias` I made for the `ls -l` command:

```
[ 18:07 root@MacBookPro / ]# alias
cd..='cd ..'
cls='clear'
df='/usr/local/bin/df.nawk'
du='du -L'
l='ls -lsG'
ldir='ls -d */'
ll='ls -lhG'
ls='ls -G'
lsdir='ls -d */'
text='open -a TextWrangler'
v='ls -lhG'
vi='vim'
vu='vim'
vv='du . --max-depth=1 -L | sort -n | cut -f2 | xargs -d "\n" du -sh -L'
xcode='open -a xcode'
```

`ln` (symlink) is a command to create a shortcut/alias.  The (very basic) syntax is:

```
 [ 18:07 root@MacBookPro / ]# ln -s [TARGET_PATH] [LINK_NAME]
```

[Here is the `ln` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln)

[Here is the `ls` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me more specifically about symlink/alias part? I still wonder why some devices are work without those remedies.

Comment: @tao Updated answer.  Let me know if anything is unclear or needs further explanation.

Comment: Thanks again. However, I still wonder why some devices work fine without installing other version of SDKs.

Comment: Because each xcode version only includes Symbols/SDKs for a specific few iOS versions, unfortunately.

Comment: However, in my case, iOS version of two devices were same. I think the  model of device is also relevant to this problem. iPhone 4G was fine without installing Symbols/SDKs but iPhone 3G was not. Anyway thanks for your help chown!!!