# Upgrade to iOS 5 caused my app to stop being debugged

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios5

I have upgraded my iphone to iOS5 to test my application behavior on iOS5

After verified it has issues, i have downgraded my device to iOS 4.3.5
since than I am trying to debug my application using XCode and get the following error:
**Error starting executable**
*No provisioned iOS device is connected.*

Does anyone know how to fix this issue - so i can debug my application again?
Edit:
Also another relevant piece of info when I use the configuration drop down selector i get 
Under Active Executable - "no device available"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue:

I took a look at the following similar question : 
[Xcode - No provisioned iOS device is connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632044/xcode-no-provisioned-ios-device-is-connected/7617785#7617785)

So i wanted to see what i see in the  snapshot that the user had  : and there it was...
I didn't see any information like he did, all i saw was 
A button called "enable for debugging" if i'm not mistaken.

Clicked on it, and Worked like a charm.... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the provisioning profile from the device via the xcode organizer window, or within the Settings App on the device.  Then add back your current prov profile from the iOS provisioning portal.

Also, make sure you have the debugging symbols/SDKs for that iOS under

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/[insert ios version folder here]
```

And:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/[insert ios version folder here]
```

Comment: Done the above and it didn't help, will try to see regarding the symbols.
I think the problem is something regarding the iOS5 upgrade.

Comment: Also, check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7497353/cannot-build-source-code-in-xcode-4-1-with-ios-4-3-5-device/7507230#7507230) on how to link in iOS symbols/SDKs for multiple xcode installs.  Hope your able to fix it @ItayLevin.

Comment: Ok, So i checked the above folder :
[Developer] has only iPhoneOS4.2.sdk
[DeviceSupport] has a directory for alot more versions including 4.3.5

Do i need the directory for 4.3.5 also to be available in the [Developer] folder?